# How can i use Javascript to count number of clicks on two #IDs and return a result depending which #ID gets the most clicks?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have to replicate a short video where there are two options for the user to click on, 'yes' or 'no'. I have assigned each 'yes' and 'no' button with the ID's `#yes` and `#no`.

Is it possible to use Javascript to count the number of user clicks on each ID and return a certain background-image class, depending on which button receives the most clicks?

Here is my code:

```
var images = ['/images/sc3.png', '/images/sc4.png', 
'/images/sc5.png', '/images/sc6.png', '/images/sc7.png'],
i = 0;

$("#yes, #no").click(function(){
   $("#background").css("background-image", "url("+ images[i]+")");
   i = (i==images.length-1) ? 0 : (i+1);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

For sure you can do it :). Let's see one way to do it:

1. Use one counter for #yes and another one for #no
2. When the user clicks a button: (i) increase the proper counter and (ii) return the most appropriate image

Here is a piece of code for doing this:

```
var images = ['/images/sc3.png', '/images/sc4.png', 
'/images/sc5.png', '/images/sc6.png', '/images/sc7.png'],
i = 0;

var yesImage = images[0];
var noImage = images[1];
var equalityImage = images[2];

var yesCount = 0;
var noCount = 0;

function selectImageBasedOnYesAndNoCount() {
  if (yesCount === noCount) {
    return equalityImage;   
  } else if (yesCount > noCount) {
    return yesImage;
  } else {
    return noImage;
  }
}

function updateBackground() {
  var imageUrl = selectImageBasedOnYesAndNoCount();
  $("#background").css("background-image", "url("+ imageUrl +")");
}

$("#yes").click(function() {
  yesCount++;
  updateBackground();
}

$("#no").click(function() {
  noCount++;
  updateBackground();
}
```

If you want to make this code better, you could use a [class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) that handle this behavior. It would improve readability and maintainability of the code, always better to do while doing this for a job ;).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this. You have the option to do using `background-image` of CSS or using the HTML tag `img`.

You will need a counter for the votes YES and NO, it is very simple.

I have done one example (it is not the best way, but it's just a simple example). Below you can find the result.

```js
// Get the buttons
let buttonYes = document.getElementById('yes');
let buttonNo = document.getElementById('no');
let buttonResult = document.getElementById('result');
// Get the images
let imageYes = document.querySelector('.image-yes');
let imageNo = document.querySelector('.image-no');
// Count the votes
let votesYes = 0;
let votesNo = 0;

buttonYes.addEventListener('click', function () {
    votesYes++;
    document.getElementById('votes-yes').innerHTML = votesYes;
});

buttonNo.addEventListener('click', function () {
    votesNo++;
    document.getElementById('votes-no').innerHTML = votesNo;
});

buttonResult.addEventListener('click', function () {
    verifyWinner(votesYes, votesNo);
});

function verifyWinner(votesYes, votesNo) {
    cleanResult();
    if (votesYes > votesNo) {
      document.querySelector('.image-yes').classList.remove('none');
    } else if (votesNo > votesYes) {
       document.querySelector('.image-no').classList.remove('none');
    } else {
        console.log('==');
    }
}

function cleanResult() {
  imageYes.classList.add('none');
  imageNo.classList.add('none');
}
```

```css
.image {
  width: 32px;
}
.none {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" id="yes">Yes</button>
<button type="button" id="no">No</button>
<button type="button" id="result">Result</button>
<p>Votes Yes: <span id="votes-yes"></span></p>
<p>Votes No: <span id="votes-no"></span></p>
<img class ="image image-yes none" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/50/Yes_Check_Circle.svg">
<img class ="image image-no none" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d5/No_sign.svg">
```